# Create a sub domain with only PHP (cross-host)

Tags: php, web, dns, cross-platform, wildcard-subdomain

I have seen a lot of solutions that involve using .htaccess. I would like to know a way to create sub domains using only PHP. For my purposes, this also needs to work using non-host-specific mechanics so it would work on most hosts.

All I know is that I would need a wildcard CNAME record that says all sub domains point to x.x.x.x, but I don’t know what to do from here. What I think you need to do is create a folder that contains the code for the sub domains, and I have done this, but I cannot find a cross-host way to link the sub domain with the folder. There has to be a way to do this as I have seen it done, but I can not find a way that meets my needs.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that PHP doesn't handle the request coming in, a web server (e.g. Apache or Nginx) does and it's the config for that software that determines where a request goes. Now the good news is that you can have wildcards in your config (at least for Apache and Nginx, YMMV if you're not using one of those), as long as you can access the config file (you'll need root access on the server). There is plenty of information available out there depending on what web server you are using so you can google that part.

Now, assuming you've done that part, in PHP you just need to check what the root domain for the request is. That information is stored in `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`, so you can use a simple script to figure out which subdomain has been requested and then launch the appropriate script for that subdomain. Something like this should do the trick:

```php
// Assuming request comes from https://subdomain.mydomain.com
$subdomain = str_replace('.mydomain.com', '', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
echo $subdomain // Outputs "subdomain"
```

This will capture multiple levels of subdomains as well, so if your request comes from `https://sub1.sub2.subdomain.mydomain.com` then `$subdomain` would contain `sub1.sub2.subdomain`.

---

### Edit after comment

You can't do this with shared hosting. Basically the config panel you get with the host, when you set up a domain or subdomain it's modifying the config file on the server for you. There's no way a host would let anyone access the config through anything other than their control panel for security. It's possible that hosts will have a similar setup to your test server, where subdomains just work as they use wildcards by default, but I don't know that and there's no guarantee of that.

WordPress itself is just blogging software. It doesn't let you set up lots of separate websites with their own installations. What WordPress Multisite (I assume that's what you mean when you mention WordPress) is use a single installation to host multiple "sites", but it's still one installation, one single database. All of the posts, all the pages, they're all stored in a single database and if you got into that database you could easily include a page from one site on another just by editing some fields in the database. It's not designed for reselling or for multiple, completely separate entities. There are a whole host of security risks in doing that sort of thing. It's designed for single entities that want to split their sites up into multiple sites, but where it's all one company, or related companies. Universities with different departments is one example I read about before, each department has their own "site" and the main IT office has a super user that can access all of them as it's on one single installation.

I could do with a little more information on what you're trying to do, but it sounds like you're trying to do something like WPEngine, where they sell hosting space and install WordPress for you. But they have dedicated servers that run scripts that create the config files and install WordPress on your own individual hosting space using their servers. That's known as SaaS (Software as a Service) and from the little you have said seems what you are trying to do. People subscribe to your site and get their own instance of the software you're selling that they access through an admin portal. That's not something they can install on their own hosting, they have to use yours. That's how most companies do this sort of thing.

Comment: Could you explain a little what I have to do in the config? The problem is that I am trying to make a web-based tool (like wordpress) that needs to create sub domains on the fly. I don’t know if my users will have root access, as on my test web server, I don’t. Most of the time you don’t. On my test server, I just put a folder in the root directory that has the name xxx.domain.com and as long as that sub domain is pointed to that server, it figures it out. However, I do not know if this is the other hosts.

Comment: @TCoder WP doesn't create subdomains on the fly, nothing in PHP has access to a server to do that. At most they can trigger scripts on a server that do it for them. I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve from the little you've given and this is a big topic. I've updated my answer with some more info as it's more than will fit in this comments section.